# How to record from many cameras without consuming all CPU

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to record using `ffmpeg.exe` by starting process of it with some parameter but `ffmpeg.exe` is eating my CPU two process of them comsume about 90% of my CPU

so how to reduce this usage to record about  20 cameras ???

**Edit:**

CPU : Xeron 2.4 GHz

fps: 28

resolution : 1280X720

bitrate : 512

Format : H264

Comment: Please give some more details .1. How much fps , resolution , bitrate , are received from cameras ? 2. What is the format receiving from camera (MJPEG or YUYV ) ? 3. What is the CPU you are using (i5 , i7 or anyother ) ?. 4. what is your system configurations ?

Comment: @abdullahfarwees done

Comment: What's your ffmpeg command?

Comment: -i rtsp://[user name]:[password]@[My IP Camera]/h264/ch1/main/av_stream -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 3600 -s 1280X720 -r 28 -b:v 128k -c:v libx264 [Storage Direction]/[File Name].flv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few search to see some `RTSP` Client how dose it works to build my own I found ffmpeg eating RAM and CPU because I tells it to process all images received from camera

### Old command used :

`-i rtsp://[user name]:[password]@[My IP Camera]/h264/ch1/main/av_stream -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 3600 -s 1280X720 -r 28 -b:v 128k -c:v libx264 [Storage Direction]/[File Name].flv`

this parameter is the problem `-s 1280X720 -r 28 -b:v 128k`

after removing this parameter it consumes 0% of CPU and around  5 - 10 MB in RAM

### New command :

`-i rtsp://[user name]:[password]@[My IP Camera]/h264/ch1/main/av_stream -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 3600 -vcodec copy[Storage Direction]/[File Name].flv`